# OnMarkerClick and JVectorMap

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I'm trying to create a map using JVectorMap that will put information to an #output div after the user clicks a given marker (for example, if the user clicks on a marker labeled Alaska, facts about Alaska pop up in the #output div).  Elsewhere on here, I've seen this code example, which outputs the name of the label...

```
onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
    $("#output").html("Some information about "+ label.html());
}
```

I'm trying to use a switch here...

```
onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
    switch (label) {
        case Alaska:
        $("#output").html($("#alaska-facts");
        [break;]

        case North Carolina:
        $("#output").html($("#nc-facts");
        [break;]

        default:
        $("#output").html("Please select a job site");
        [break;]
    }
}
```

The map doesn't display when I run this code, and I may be on the wrong track altogether.   Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

- The `label` is an object and will not match the simple `case` statements matching string values. You might want to evaluate against `label.text()`
- The values in the `case` should be quoted strings (i.e. `"North Carolina"`, not `North Carolina`)
- The `break;` should not be wrapped in `[]` (you don't want an array of `break`, you want to break out of the `switch`).
- You are missing a closing `)` for the lines setting the `.html()` with jQuery ID selectors

Corrected example:

```
onRegionLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
   switch (label.text()) {
      case "Alaska":
         $("#output").html($("#alaska-facts"));
         break;

      case "North Carolina":
         $("#output").html($("#nc-facts"));
         break;

      default:
         $("#output").html("Please select a job site");
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: That's the ticket!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!